# Need detail explaination about "In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be the same"

Tags: matlab

So far, i don't get any ideas to understand this error mean. If I have, I think I could solve this problem in my matlab programming.

If anyone could help me to explain what's going on and give some example?

Answer (score 8):

If `I` is a logical matrix

```
I = 
    1 0 1 1 0
```

and `A` is an array of the same size,

```
A = 
    5 3 8 1 2
```

then

```
>> A(I) 
ans = 
    5 8 1
```

i.e., `I` works as a mask for the elements in `A`. You can also use this for assigment:

```
>> A(I) = 4
A = 
    4 3 4 4 2
```

(scalar assignment), or

```
>> A(I) = [1 NaN 3]
A = 
    1 3 NaN 3 2
```

(array assignment). You get the error if you try to do something like

```
>> A(I) = [ 7 6 5 4 8 7 6 8 7 9 4 3 2]
```

i.e., `A(I)` refers to a different number of elements than `[7 6 5 4 8 7 6 8 7 9 4 3 2]` contains. This is *only* valid when assigning with a scalar or empty value

```
A(I) = []      %# valid 
A(I) = 4       %# valid
A(I) = [1 2 3] %# valid, numel(A(I)) == numel([1 2 3])
A(I) = [1 2]   %# NOT VALID, numel(A(I)) != numel([1 2])
```

Comment: Can't vector I also just be a vector of linear indices, doesn't have to be logical? For example I would expect A([1 3 4]) = [1 2 3 4]  to also give that error. This way A and I can have different dimensions but B and I must be the same.

Comment: @Dan: That is true. If `I` is a regular integer array, `size(I)==size(B)` must hold, or `numel(B) == 1` or `numel(B) == 0`.